# Is there a way that I can print out the important parts of an exception in my Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an exception that is getting called:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("MainPage: exception");
}
```

Is there any method out there that would be able to handle and show most of what I might need to know about in the exception and print this with a Debt.Writeline like I am doing?

Comment: "what I might need to know about in the exception" How should we know what you consider to be important? There is the exceptions stacktrace and its message. Just print that information you need. I don´t understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Debug.WriteLine(ex);
```

or

```
Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
```